# Not enough power to the Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: power, power-supply

I have a problem with my Raspberry Pi B+. First the problem was that I didn't get the keyboard or mouse to work and I have now found out that the Pi do not get enough power. When I looked on forums, they said the watt or whatever it is, should be between 4,75 and 5,25. When I check mine, it only have 3,30. This is probably enough to start the Pi, but not enough to run the USB ports. I have tried many different cables, both tried with normal cell phone charger and with iPad charger with another cable. But all of them give the same amount.

This may sound a little weird that all of them give the same amount of power, do you think I might check the power the wrong place on the Pi? I only find guides on how to check power on the normal, not the B+.

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to carefully check the voltage.  You can measure the voltage between pin 2 (5V) and pin 6 (ground).  It should read around 5V.

See http://www.keytosmart.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Raspberry-Pi-GPIO-Layout-Model-B-Plus.png

Comment: Ok thanks for a little help. When I checked on the places you said I was gonna, I shower 5,06 now, which Is enough.

Comment: It may drop to a lower voltage as you power more kit from the Pi (e.g. plug in a USB device).  If it drops below about 4.5V the Pi may reboot.

Comment: This still does not fix the problem that my keyboard and mouse don't work.

Comment: Did you measure the voltage with the keyboard and mouse attached?  If it's still around 5V then power is not your problem.

Comment: It measured the same voltage with and without keyboard and mouse.

Comment: That suggests power is not the problem.  It might be worth editing your original post to include the output of lsusb (with the mouse and keyboard connected).  This of course assumes you can remote login to your Pi.